# Derivatives in Computation graph

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, backpropagation, derivative

[image]
In Advanced Learning Algorithms by Andrew Ng, Coursera:

> One thing that makes backprop efficient is you
> notice that when we do the right-to-left calculation,
> we had to compute this term,
> the derivative of j with respect to a just once.
> This quantity is then used to compute both the derivative
> of j with respect to **w** and
> the derivative of j with respect to **b**.

We wonder why not the derivative
of j with respect to **c** and
the derivative of j with respect to **b**, as mentioned below.
[image]

Or it's just a mistake and we wonder where to find the errata.
Coursera and deeplearning.ai were searched but nothing.

Thank you for your help.